# What is the best, and cleanest way to close a file in Java inside a finally block

Tags: java, file-handling, ioexception

I wrote a method to close write to a file.
However, a senior developer suggested me to close the file inside the finally block.

This is the method I have:

```
private static void writetoFiles(String error) {
    try {
        File file = new File("errorcode.txt");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
    } else {
            FileWriter updateerrorcode = new FileWriter("errorcode.txt");
            updateerrorcode.write(error);
            updateerrorcode.close();
     }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

I read many answers in stackoverflow but all of them seemed a bit too complicated for a simple case like mine.
Any suggestions how should I go about this?

Comment: try-with-resources: `try (FileWriter updateerrorcode = new FileWriter("DatabaseErrorCode.txt")) { updateerrorcode.write(error); }`

Comment: Yes, exactly what Johannes Kuhn says. Use try-with-resources, so that the resource will automatically be closed when the resource goes out of scope.

Answer (score 3):

The cleanest approach would be to do it using the [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement as shown below:

```
private static void writetoFiles(String error) throws IOException {
    //...

    try (FileWriter updateerrorcode = new FileWriter("errorcode.txt")) {
        updateerrorcode.write(error);
    }

    //...
}
```

**Do not catch an exception in a method if it can not handle it:**

If the method, `writetoFiles` can not handle the exception, it should throw the same so that the calling method can handle it appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [try-with-resource statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html):

```
private static void writetoFiles(String error) {
    try {
        File file = new File("errorcode.txt");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        } else {
            try (FileWriter updateerrorcode = new FileWriter("errorcode.txt")) {
                updateerrorcode.write(error);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO: Handle error condition
    }
}
```

To point out a separate issue...I think your logic is wrong in your example.  If the output file doesn't exist, all your code does is create the file.  Only if the file already exists does it write the `error` text to it.  I expect that you want to write the text in either case.  If this is true, you don't need the `createNewFile` call at all, as the `FileWriter` class will create the file if it doesn't already exist.  So I think what you really want is this:

```
private static void writetoFiles(String error) {
    try (FileWriter updateerrorcode = new FileWriter("errorcode.txt")) {
        updateerrorcode.write(error);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO: Handle error condition
    }
}
```

This will cause the writer to be properly closed in both the normal execution case and the error throw case.  I assume that in your actual code, you'll do something with that `IOException` when it is caught.  I can't know what you want to do there, so I won't propose anything.

If you want to strictly use a `finally` block, you can do this instead:

```
FileWriter updateerrorcode = new FileWriter("errorcode.txt");
try {
    updateerrorcode.write(error);
}
catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO: Handle error condition
}
finally {
    updateerrorcode.close();
}
```

This is the only option you would have had in earlier versions of Java, prior to the addition of the try-with-resource construct.  In this second method, you might want to catch an error from `close()`, but in all of my 25+ years of experience with Java, I don't recall a `close()` call on a file failing.  I guess you'd get that if you were out of disk space on your target volume and so `close()` couldn't flush the stream's write buffer.  This issue is a distinct advantage of the newer method...failure to close the file won't affect the throw/catch of an exception thrown by the `write()` call.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn - don't want to take your points.  Just thought this deserved to be a true answer. If you copy/paste this answer under your own name, I'll delete my copy.

Comment: Is it really try-with-resource statement?

Comment: Will the finally block have access to the variable created under the try resource?I doubt so.

Comment: 3 things, try-with-resource is something like this: try (FileWriter updateerrorcode = new FileWriter("DatabaseErrorCode.txt"))... what about exceptions in the finally block? and the last how the variable will be visible in finally block speaking of the first snippet.

Comment: Your answer includes the empty catch block of the code in the question. I think that should be removed or altered to throw a runtime exception.

Comment: @Damanpreet - I don't see the issue you're asking about.  I don't give an example that has both a `try-with-resource` statement and a `finally` block.

Comment: @tgdavies - I added a comment to the empty block before seeing your comment. I struggle with this issue when providing answers.  It isn't clear to me if additional issues like the one you point out should be addressed in the answer to a question, as they don't enhance the answer to the specific question.  I don't have an issue with it either way.  I don't think it is an error on the part of the answerer to not address such an issue as long as the answer isn't what introduced it.

Comment: @BelaVizer In that first code sample, the second `try`, nested within the first, is the try-with-resources. I too missed it on first reading. That is why I prefer code-formatting where the parantheses are broken out to separate lines to make a try-with-resources more obvious.